# Proof that finite-dimensional Wiener process distributions are Gaussian

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I have to prove that finite-dimensional Wiener process distributions are Gaussian and calculate them. How should I start? I know the definition and properties of Wiener process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**: For $t_1<t_2<\cdots <t_n$, the vector
$$
W=(W_{t_1},W_{t_2}-W_{t_1},W_{t_3}-W_{t_2},\ldots,W_{t_n}-W_{t_{n-1}})
$$
is multivariate Gaussian (why?). Now, use that
$$
(W_{t_1},\ldots, W_{t_n})=f(W),
$$
where $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=(x_1,x_1+x_2,\ldots,x_1+\ldots+x_n)$.